# Default selector background in Clickable Views

Tags: android, css-selectors, drawable

I have some clickable views and I want to set the default available background that is present on list click (in ICS is a blue color). I have tried putting as background this:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
```

but it is not the default blue I have by default (the one I used is orange). What is the drawable used by default on android as click selector?

Thanks

Comment: use android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's `list_selector_holo_dark` or the equivalent holo light version; and these are the defaults in Honeycomb and above. `list_selector_background` is the non-holo version, used in Gingerbread and below.

**EDIT**: I *believe* (but can't confirm) that the platform agnostic selector is [`?android:attr/listSelector`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listSelector)

Comment: and which is the default theme independent selector?

Comment: There isn't one I'm afraid. If you want to use the ICS (blue) one on all versions of Android, you'll have to copy the drawable resources into your own project. Alternatively if you want to use the default one for each version of Android, you'd have to make two versions of your clickable view, one in `\layout\ ` which uses `@android:drawable/list_selector_background` and one in `\layout-v11\ ` which uses `@android:drawable/list_selector_holo_dark`

Comment: By the way the @android:drawable/list_selector_holo_dark is not public so I cannot use it in layouts

Comment: ok. Well you can just copy the relevant files into your project (the list_selector_holo_dark.xml file and all the drawable files it references; you'll have to open the xml file to see what it drawables it uses), and use it from there. Don't forget you'll need to reference them using "@drawable/...", not "@android:drawable/..."

Comment: this defeats the purpose of using default Android resources, which are updated every time there's an update. I don't want to copy a GREEN selector and then see they've updated the default listView selector to PINK with their next release.

Comment: @Matroska list_selector_holo_dark is not available publicly in the SDK.  You need to use this website to generate the resources: http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: @Matroska It's `android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator`, which can be confirmed by searching for `list_selector_holo_dark` in sdk source `res/values/themes.xml`. `android:attr/listSelector` is the attribute value used by `AbsListView` to retrieve xml value `android:listSelector`, if you use this as the value for an attribute, normally an exception will be thrown inside `TypedValue.getDrawable()`.

Answer (score 178):

This works for me:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: put it in a v11 folder. Simple as that, welcome to Android ;-)

Comment: or `    android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator"
`

Comment: Using `?attr/selectableItemBackground` with Android support library works on versions 2.x as well. On Gingerbread it gave me a blue background (on the emulator) and a light gray one on a KitKat device.

Comment: Nice, works perfect. Do you know how can I change the color?

Comment: How do I force it to use the light version of it, instead of the dark version ?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `appcompat-v7`, you can just use `?attr/selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: Is it possible to customize it, so that the color will be different?

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to combine all the valid answers:

Define a attribute (eg. in values/attrs.xml):

```
<attr name="clickableItemBackground" format="reference"/>
```

In your platform dependent theme section (eg. in values/styles.xml or values/themes.xml) declare this:

```
<style name="Theme.Platform" parent="@android:style/Theme.Whatever">
        <item name="clickableItemBackground">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
</style>
```

In your platform dependent theme section for api-11+ (eg. in values-v11/styles.xml or values-v11/themes.xml) declare this:

```
<style name="Theme.Platform" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Whatever">
        <item name="clickableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Then use `?attr/clickableItemBackground` wherever needed.

Answer (score 6):

A solution similar to flx's answer, but without additional attribute definition.

Platform independent style used for pre-Holo devices (in `res\values\styles.xml`):

```
<style name="SelectableItem">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
</style>
```

Style for Holo devices (API Level 14+) (in `res\values-v14\styles.xml`):

```
<style name="SelectableItem">
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Apply style to needed view, e.g., `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/SelectableItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Finally something that works, without having to create different layout files. The "background" and "attr" tags don't work with the "drawable" tag, which is required for the selector states, and so all other solutions on this page don't work.

Answer (score 6):

This works fine on api 11 and above. But as noted it wont work on previous versions.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Here is a solution to have it run on **all versions** running android.

1. Add the appropriate colors within the colors.xml which is located within your values folder. It should appear as such:

   ```
   <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
   <color name="blue">#7ecce8</color>
   ```
2. Create an xml selector file. Here I named it button_selection.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/>         <!--pressed -->
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
   <item android:drawable="@color/white"/> <!-- default -->
   </selector>
   ```
3. Go to your view or button and set the newly created button_selection.xml as its background.

   ```
   android:background="@drawable/button_selection"
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

```
android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator
```

if you just want the items to highlight blue (or whatever the current default is) while they are clicked.

Comment: No, that will not default to list_selector_holo_dark on JellyBean devices.  Still highlights list items with yellow-orange color (Gingerbread style).

Comment: works fine, `emulator-api4.0-blue`, `emulator-nexus4-api4.1.1-blue`, `device-nexus4-api4.4.2-gray`

Answer (score 3):

Setting `Background` restricts you from choosing a background color or drawable later!
So my advice is to add this style to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="TouchableView">
    <item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

And then on every view you only need to add:

```
            android:theme="@style/TouchableView"
```

Like **ANY** VIEW!

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_orders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/TouchableView"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/my_orders"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

**Don't forget** to add `onClickListener` to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

In short -  `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` **;)**

Comment: How do you resolve this at runtime?

Comment: How do you resolve this at runtime?