# Remove pressed color on Spinner

Tags: android, colors, spinner, pressed

I'd like to remove the blue color (I'm testing my app with Holo) appearing when I click on a Spinner.

My code :

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), 
            R.layout.spinner_item, string_array);
    array_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(array_adapter);
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:background="@drawable/item"
    style="@style/EquidiaTheme.MySpinner" />
```

and item.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

This doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: I don't. I want the item to show NO color at all when selected / pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Customize `android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle`

[Styling ActionBar dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479186/styling-actionbar-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid the blue rectangle on item when I select it when I done this:
First I declare color that I want to use in values.xml:

```
<resources>
   <drawable name="red_color">#ff0000</drawable>
   <drawable name="blue_color">#0000ff</drawable>
   <drawable name="green_color">#00ff00</drawable>
   <drawable name="transparent_color">#00000000</drawable>
</resources>
```

Than I define custom style in Styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Spinner" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/transparent_color</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

in the style I was able to use only colors defined in resources ( Setting color like: @android:color/XXX or #XXX directly in style didn't work)

After all I aplly the them on Activity. I use Xamarin so may code is:

```
[Activity( Label = "TestLayouts", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme="@style/Theme.Spinner")]
```

but for android it should be:
   `<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Spinner">`

I use this answer for reference:
[Default selector background in Clickable Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250215/default-selector-background-in-clickable-views)

also to get rid the blue rectangle on spinner itself use:

```
 <Spinner 
   android:background="@null"
```

You need to use both to completly remove blue rectable.
Also maybe this attributes in style may help you:

```
    <item name="android:attr/colorPressedHighlight">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:attr/colorLongPressedHighlight">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/red_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without theme. Ideal if you only got a few spinner.

create a drawable (xml) with state (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

use the SAME image for the state PRESSED and NORMAL

then use it as background :

```
mySpinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_spinner_state_drawable)
```

extra tips:

- you can use system drawable (image) from the system resource: like "@android: drawable/btn_dropdown_normal". It is easier to maintain and give a more native look and feel.
- ref http://androiddrawables.com/Buttons.html