# Default background color for pressed item in ListView / GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, background, resources

I'm trying to make a selectable GridView. So I need the default color for this (when you click on item it should stay selected). I just need the default (light-blue) color for pressed items (like the blue in listview).

`view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your getView() method and XML?.. Also, are you using a custom selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. [A very similar question has been asked here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250215/default-selector-background-in-clickable-views)

In short, this should be your answer:

> It's list_selector_holo_dark or the equivalent holo light version; and
>   these are the defaults in Honeycomb and above.
>   list_selector_background is the non-holo version, used in Gingerbread
>   and below.

To be clear, I am quoting /u/Espiandev.