# Color values for Buttons (Normal state) in holo dark theme ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-theme

Need help regarding the color codes for buttons in HOLO DARK theme ICS. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947156/what-are-the-default-color-values-the-holo-theme-on-android-4-0) throws light into all the color codes for Holo theme except for the buttons in normal state. Thanks in advance. 
[basic buttons](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html#basic) holo theme ics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ive got it now. If you want the default colors of Android ICS; you just have to go to your Android SDK and look after platforms\android-15\data\res\values and then colors. 
There you go:

```
 <!-- For holo theme -->
    <drawable name="screen_background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</drawable>
    <drawable name="screen_background_holo_dark">#ff000000</drawable>
    <color name="background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_holo_dark">@android:color/background_holo_light</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_holo_light">@android:color/background_holo_dark</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark">#ff4c4c4c</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light">#ffb2b2b2</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_inverse_holo_dark">@android:color/bright_foreground_holo_light</color>
    <color name="bright_foreground_inverse_holo_light">@android:color/bright_foreground_holo_dark</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_holo_dark">#bebebe</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_disabled_holo_dark">#80bebebe</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_inverse_holo_dark">#323232</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_inverse_disabled_holo_dark">#80323232</color>
    <color name="hint_foreground_holo_dark">#808080</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_holo_light">#323232</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_disabled_holo_light">#80323232</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_inverse_holo_light">#bebebe</color>
    <color name="dim_foreground_inverse_disabled_holo_light">#80bebebe</color>
    <color name="hint_foreground_holo_light">#808080</color>
    <color name="highlighted_text_holo_dark">#6633b5e5</color>
    <color name="highlighted_text_holo_light">#6633b5e5</color>
    <color name="link_text_holo_dark">#5c5cff</color>
    <color name="link_text_holo_light">#0000ee</color>
```

This for the Background:

```
 <color name="background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
 <color name="background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
```

Probably you wont get the same colors if you look this up in Photoshop etc. because its set up with Alpha values.