# Color used in Button in Holo Theme dark

Tags: android, android-theme

Which color is used in Button in Normal state in Android Theme holo_dark?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375511/color-values-for-buttons-normal-state-in-holo-dark-theme-ics) and have added color images corresponding to the color name but none matches the color used in Button normal state theme holo_dark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which color they use, but you can look into their 9Patch background drawables. You can find it [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_normal_holo_dark.9.png). <s>Note that it uses an alpha value, so you can't really find out what color it is(at least I don't know how it could be possible).</s>

**Edit:**

Ok, I did find out how to find out the opacity with photoshop. You can see that in the info window. So now that's the color:

Alpha: 40% 
Red: 153
Green: 153
Blue: 153

The color would be this: 
`#66999999`

Comment: You are very close, but it is a little bit darker.

Answer (score 1):

I've just also wanted to replicate the colour of an Android standard button in my own app and it appears that the colour used is as follows:

```
Red: 188
Green: 188
Blue: 188
```

This converted into Hex code is:

```
#BCBCBC.
```

Obviously this doesn't include the fact that Android includes borders etc. on their buttons but this is the base colour used. Hope this helps!