# selecting resources from gui instead of using XML

Tags: android

I'm able to select android provided colors in xml using `@android:color/black` etc but I'm unable to find `android` option in `Reference Chooser` GUI.Is there a way?

I remember that I found `android` in Reference chooser sometime back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this using the Reference Chooser GUI.

What you can do is visit the field in the xml view, type "@android:" as the value for the specific entry you wish to edit and then press CMD+SPACE on mac or CTRL+SPACE on windows to show the autocomplete options. Here you will be able to navigate the resources available to you.

Comment: yeah I'm doing the same.ty

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default Android, then you can look into the Android SDK under this path:

> `platforms\android-<API Level>\data\res\values\colors.xml.`

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382463/1333975) I gave a while back.