# Navigation drawer is displaying incorrect theme

Tags: android, colors, navigation, android-theme, navigation-drawer

I've recently implemented a navigation drawer in an app that I'm working on, and I've noticed it hasn't taken on my app theme `Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`. Shouldn't the nav drawer have the same style as this theme, which would be that light-gray background and dark gray text? Currently it has a black background with white text. How would I go about having my navigation drawer's theme consistent with the rest of the app? I don't think I can set the theme/style to the layout of the drawer nor can I do it programatically. Is this something I must do manually? If so, does anyone know the hex values for the dark gray text and light-gray background, as I can't seem to access the default resource that contains these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to theme the navigation drawer manually, it doesn't inherit the parent theme. Here's a question that contains a list of all the Holo colors: [What are the default color values for the Holo theme on Android 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947156/what-are-the-default-color-values-for-the-holo-theme-on-android-4-0/10382463#10382463)

Comment: I've visited that page before and couldn't use it, but I think I am just having trouble discerning what color resources I'm actually looking for. For example, the "background" color I was looking for is actually "dim_foreground", but this is my own mistake. I'll try to use this further, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Android can be weird in what colors it uses where, your best option is to either screenshot something with the color you want and then use a tool to inspect what the color is, or just brute-force all the colors until you find the one you want.