# Android Holo Selected List Item Color

Tags: android, android-theme

Can someone tell me the corresponding color code of a selected list item in Holo? Also, what are the colors to generate a long press list item transition in Holo? I know the Holo colors are defined in colors.xml but I'm unsure which ones are used for the selection and long press list item transition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have a look at Android's platform framework base, especially the `themes.xml` file, you will find the answer to your question:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

This file defines, amongst others, the following two Holo themes and its corresponding items:

**Theme.Holo:**

```
<style name="Theme.Holo">
    ...
    <item name="colorPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**Theme.Holo.Light:**

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light" parent="Theme.Light">
    ...
    <item name="colorPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    ...
</style>
```

I think these are the two colours you are looking for.
The colours are translated into the following hex codes:

```
<!-- A light Holo shade of blue -->
<color name="holo_blue_light">#ff33b5e5</color>

<!-- A really bright Holo shade of blue -->
<color name="holo_blue_bright">#ff00ddff</color>
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, if I change my app theme to:     <style name="Theme.ServeStream" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@android:color/white</item>
     <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@android:color/white</item>
    </style> then the color of a selected list item should be white. This doesn't change the list selected color. I don't think colorPressedHighlight and colorLongPressedHighlight correspond to selected color, any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's a totally different question. You asked for the color codes for the click states "pressed" and "longpressed" which I have both provided above. The way you are trying to apply these values is wrong! Have a look at [Android ListView Selector Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color) to change the default colours.

Comment: From the question: "Can someone tell me the corresponding color code of a selected list item in Holo?". Regardless, do you know what these colors are?

Comment: Have you read my answer? It's **#ff33b5e5** and **#ff00ddff**.

Answer (score 11):

You could try this :

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

You could also refer to

[How do you get the selection color in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745573/how-do-you-get-the-selection-color-in-android/14942479#14942479)

and

[Default selector background in Clickable Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250215/default-selector-background-in-clickable-views)